# How to make an entry to JSON file

Tags: python, json

How can I simply add a line to a JSON file. In the first part of the code a JSON file is generated. In the while-loop I want to only make an entry to the code instead of generating the whole document new every loop. The 'data' string grows every second and therefore makes generating a new JSON more complex with every loop.
I am working with Python 2.7 since my BeagleBoneBlack runs that.

```
import json
from time import sleep
# Make it work for Python 2+3 and with Unicode
import io
try:
    to_unicode = unicode
except NameError:
    to_unicode = str

Val1=123
Val2=321
timesteps = 1

data = [{'Timestep': timesteps, 'Cur1': Val1, 'Cur2': Val2}]

# Write JSON file for Current
with io.open('data.json', 'w', encoding='utf8') as outfile:
    str_ = json.dumps(data,
        indent=4, sort_keys=True,
        separators=(',', ': '), ensure_ascii=False)
    outfile.write(to_unicode(str_))

#here the Loop starts
while True:

    if timesteps < 50:
        timesteps = timesteps + 1

        Val1=123
        Val2=321

        data.insert(len(data), {'Timestep': timesteps, 'Cur1': Val1, 'Cur2': Val2})

        # Write JSON file again
        with io.open('Current.json', 'w', encoding='utf8') as outfile:
            str_ = json.dumps(data,
                          indent=4, sort_keys=True,
                          separators=(',', ': '), ensure_ascii=False)
            outfile.write(to_unicode(str_))
        print "Entry successfull"
        sleep(1)
    else:
        print "Time up!"
        break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by giving an exit command that ends the loop and saves the JSON only once.
During the loop itself only the data is aquired but no JSON saved.
If you guys want the whole code, let me know.